# App seems to close when in background

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

Some times my windows store app disappear from Alt-Tab List, if user finds app via top left corner app list and re-opens it then it re-launches completely.What is the reason? How can i handle this issue in my windows store

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour. Windows will suspend or even shut down your app when it has been in the background for some time.
You should handle `checkpoint`, `suspend` and `resume` events in your app and also use the [`previousExecutionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.previousexecutionstate.aspx) information of the launch activation event to restore state after launching. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx) for further information.